# TypeError: MemberStore.members.map is not a function

Tags: reactjs, api, mobx

I am build a small web app using React and Mobx.  Then end result is to communicate to a Rails backend which I have setup.  Now I have created a MemberStore which has a async fetchAll() method.

```
import {observable, action, computed} from 'mobx';

class MemberStore {
@observable members = [];
@observable isLoading = false;

@action async fetchAll() {
    this.isLoading = false;
    const response = await fetch('http://localhost:3000/v1/members');
    const status = await response.status;
    if (status === 200) {
        this.members = response.json();
    } 

}
```

Now this links up with my Contact page which has a React lifecycle method of `componentWillMount`. When it tried to render the items using a map function I get the error above. Below is the code for the contact page.

```
class Contact extends Component {
componentWillMount(){
    this.props.MemberStore.fetchAll();
}
handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const name = this.member.value;
    const email = this.email.value;
    // const email = this.email.value;
    this.props.MemberStore.addMember({name, email});
    this.member.value = '';
    this.email.value = '';
}
render() {
    const {MemberStore} = this.props;

    return (
        <div>
            <Navbar />
            <Jumbotron title="Contact Page" subtitle="You want to get in   touch"/>
            <div className="container">
               <h2>You have {MemberStore.memberCount} members.</h2>

               <form onSubmit={e => this.handleSubmit(e)}>
                   <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Your Name" ref={input => this.member = input }/>
                   <div>
                   <input type="text" placeholder= "Enter Your Email" ref={input => this.email = input }/>
                   </div>
                   <button>Submit</button>
               </form>
               <ul>
                {MemberStore.members.map(({name, email}, index) => (
                    <li key={index}>
                    <div>
                        name: {name}
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        email: {email}
                    </div>
                    </li>
                ))}
              </ul>
            </div>
            <Footer />
        </div>
      )
  }
 }
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is the expected skeleton response of your members api? Are you sure you want to set `isLoading` to false before you have actually received the data (so before the `await` statement?)

Comment: I realise that it is not allowing CORS and therefore I would need to make adjustments to the Rails Backend.

Comment: Try `console.log(MemberStore.members)` and make sure it's an array.

Comment: like this ```{MemberStore.members.map(({name, email}, index) => (
                       
                        <li key={index}>
                        <div>
                            name: {name}
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            email: {email}
                            console.log(MemberStore.members)
                        </div>
                        </li>
                    ))}```

Comment: @AltBrian you can place the `console.log` before the `render` method's  `return`. The goal is to see if `MemberStore.members` is actually an array because the error you're receiving is usually because you're trying to `map` something other than an array.

Comment: I will once my Mac has come on. For some reason it has randomly restarted.

Answer (score 0):

`response.json()` is a promise, so you need to `await` that, too. Assuming your API is returning an array as the response, it should work:

```
@action async fetchAll() {
    this.isLoading = false;
    const response = await fetch('http://localhost:3000/v1/members');
    const status = await response.status;
    if (status === 200) {
        this.members = await response.json();
    }
}
```

Comment: I have also been told that my Ruby backend is also using port 3000. So I will need to change that first.